# Removing a symlink

Tags: macos, mamp, symlink

A few weeks ago I created a symlink on my local machine, at that time it worked fine, but now I realised I created a wrong link and now everything on my localhost is pointing to one particular folder.

I completely forget where I created this link though, so I'm not sure how to remove it now.

I'm using MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways of understanding your problem.

One is that you set your document root (localhost:8888, the default in MAMP) in the File -> Preferences -> Apache -> Document Root  to something you didn't intend.

In that case, it is simple enough to simply choose another document root at that location.

A second possibility I see is that, using the terminal, you added a symlink from that document root to some new location, in which case you can return to the terminal, navigate to the document root and, only if you are sure that this is a symlink, simply

```
 rm symlink_name
```

which will remove the link.

Comment: My document root is still the default MAMP one.

Like I explained, I created a bad symlink a few weeks ago, and that's also the problem, I forgot where or which symlink I created, so i have no way of removing it.

Comment: So you have created a symlink from the default MAMP document root to some other place. So, using terminal, navigate to your document root, or rather that directory above it. If you do `ls -al` you should see the link and where it points, for example: `lrwxr-xr-x   1 myuser  staff    25 Oct  2 16:18 mysymlink -> /Users/fool/Other/folder`

Comment: then you merely need to remove the link (which is also the document root of MAMP) which is done with `rm mysymlink` and point the document root to something else, or if you like, just recreate a simple folder at the same location (this time not symlinked). That way your localhost (that is, the document root of MAMP) will no longer point to the linked directory.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just tried this, but I can't find any link in there